# Is there a way to conect the input/output of a console application to the output/input of another program

Tags: input, console, output

I have an application i cannot edit that reads from the console and writes to it and i want to know how i can read what the program is saying and write back commands to the program.

This is for a minecraft server where i want to read what the players are saying and run commands acoording to what is said. (the server is the application i cannot edit)

I cannot create a modification for the server, because i am using a mod that checks if there are any other modifications done to the files and fails to load if that is the case.

Comment: It's unclear what you asking (at least for me). Do you want to write an application that interacts with the console and in this case what language do you want to use?

Comment: I want to write an application that controls an already existing application. basically, the already existing application has console i/o where it says what is happening.
I want to take what the application is saying and if specific conditions are met, send a string to the input of that application like "save current state" or "stop execution"

the programming language doesn't matter, as long as it can be used to write a program to talk with another program via the console.

basically, i want a program that can mimic human interaction in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple app in c# to get started with, to redirect the I/O streams you need to start the application (in this case the server) within your own application.

First we create a new instance of the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class

```cs
var process = new Process();
```

then we specify the start info

```cs
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = Console.ReadLine(), //Reads executable path from console
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};
```

then we add an event handler, in this example it's just writes the lines with a "> " prefix

```cs
process.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) => Console.WriteLine($"> {e.Data}");
```

and now we can start the process by calling `Process#Start()`

```cs
process.Start();
```

and finally we can call `Process#BeginOutputReadLine()` without this the `OutputDataReceived` event will never trigger

```cs
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

To send commands you can use the process' `StandardInput` stream

```cs
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("command");
```

The fully working code with example output (tested with cmd.exe, but it's must work with MC servers)
Code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Enter executable path: ");
    var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = Console.ReadLine(), //Reads executable path, for example cmd is the input
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };
    process.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) => Console.WriteLine($"> {e.Data}");
    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();

    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo a");

    //Prevent closing
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:

```cs
Enter executable path: cmd
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.239]
> (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Minden jog fenntartva.
>
> F:\VisualStudio\StackOverflow\StackOverflow\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1>echo a
> a
>
```